# How to Update ACF Field value using Rest API in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, rest, advanced-custom-fields, wordpress-rest-api

i want to update my acf field present in a page using REST API, how can i do that, it is very difficult to me as i searched everywhere but didnt get my answer

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and sticked together this javascript-code from various sources, which works great now:

```
      const username = 'your_wp_username'
      const pass = 'your_wp_appliaction_password'
      const token = window.btoa(`${username}:${pass}`)
      const url = 'https://yoururl.com/wp-json/acf/v3/projects/384?fields[title]=Better title';
      const params = {
        'cache': 'no-cache',
        'method': 'PATCH',
        'credentials': 'omit',
        'headers': {
          'Authorization': `Basic ${token}`,
          'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8; application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        },
      }
      fetch(url,params)
      .then((res) => {
        return res.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data)
      })
```

Make sure to replace the following variables in my code:

**your_wp_username** 
You can find your wordpress-username in: WP-Backend --> User --> Edit

**your_wp_application_password** 
You can generate an Application Specific Password in:
WP-Backend --> User --> Edit --> Scroll to the bottom or by following this [guide](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2020/11/05/application-passwords-integration-guide/). The password will look something like this: `XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX`

**your_url**

- Make sure to change the url `https://yoururl.com/wp-json/acf/v3/projects/` to your custom API endpoint.
- The number `384` after the endpoint is the ID of the element / post we're updating in this request
- The word `title` in the url is the fieldname we're updating